# Exercise 9, Section 2.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $W_1+W_2=V$ and $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$. Prove that for each vector $\alpha$ in $V$ there are unique vectors $\alpha_1$ in $W_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in $W_2$ such that $\alpha =\alpha_1 +\alpha_2$.

Rephrasing problem to my taste:

> Let $W_1,W_2\leq V$. $W_1+W_2=V$ and $W_1\cap W_2=\{0_V\}$$\iff$If $\alpha\in V$, then $\exists !\alpha_1\in W_1$, $\exists !\alpha_2\in W_2$ such that $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$.

**My attempt:** Let $\alpha \in V$. Since $W_1+W_2=V$, we have $\alpha = \alpha_1+ \alpha_2$ ; $\alpha_i\in W_i$, $\forall i\in \{1,2\}$. Let $\beta_1\in W_1$ and $\beta_2\in W_2$ such that $\alpha = \beta_1 + \beta_2$. So $\alpha = \alpha_1+ \alpha_2= \beta_1 + \beta_2$. By elementary property of vector space, $\alpha_1 -\beta_1 =\beta_2-\alpha_2$. Since $W_1,W_2\leq V$, we have $\alpha_1 -\beta_1\in W_1$ and $\beta_2-\alpha_2\in W_2$. So $\alpha_1 -\beta_1 =\beta_2-\alpha_2\in W_1\cap W_2$. Since $W_1\cap W_2=\{0_V\}$, we have $\alpha_1 -\beta_1 =\beta_2-\alpha_2=0_V$. Thus $\alpha_1=\beta_1$ and $\alpha_2=\beta_2$. Hence $\exists ! \alpha_1\in W_1$, $\exists !\alpha_2\in W_2$ such that $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$. **Is my proof correct?**

I think, one can also solve this problem by contradiction, i.e. $\exists\beta_1\in W_1$, $\exists \beta_2\in W_2$ such that $\alpha_1\neq \beta_1$, $\alpha_2\neq \beta_2$ and $\alpha=\beta_1 +\beta_2$.

**Edit:** ($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $\forall \alpha\in V$, $\exists  !\alpha_1\in W_1$, $\exists !\alpha_2\in W_2$ such that $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$. So $V=W_1+W_2$. Claim: $W_1\cap W_2=\{0_V\}$. Proof: let $x\in W_1 \cap W_2$. Since $x\in W_1\cap W_2\leq V$, we have $-x\in W_1\cap W_2$. So $x+(-x)\in W_1\cap W_2\subseteq V$. We have $x+(-x)=0_V=0_V+0_V$. By uniqueness, $x=0_V\in \{0_V\}$. Thus $W_1\cap W_2\subseteq \{0_V\}$. $0_V\in W_1\cap W_2$. Hence $W_1\cap W_2=\{0_V\}$.

Comment: It's a fine proof. My only suggestion would be to study the way proofs are written in Hoffman and try to imitate them. Your proof as written is somewhat difficult to read. Math is like any art. Eventually you will develop your own style for writing clear and concise proofs, but only after imitating the style of more experienced mathematicians.

Comment: The only actual error I see is the final paragraph when you talk about a proof by contradiction.  Do you see why your assumptions there wouldn't give a valid proof of the theorem?

Comment: @BrianMoehring no . Can you please tell why my assumption is wrong?

Comment: In the proof of uniqueness, if we assume $\alpha_1 \neq \beta_1$ and $\alpha_2 \neq \beta_2$ and $\alpha = \beta_1 + \beta_2$, then the conclusion would be "$\alpha_1 = \beta_1$ OR $\alpha_2 = \beta_2$", which isn't what you want.  The assumption for a proof by way of contradiction would be "$\alpha = \beta_1 + \beta_2$ and either $\alpha_1 \neq \beta_1$ or $\alpha_2 \neq \beta_2$".  In doing so, however, you end up splitting the proof into two sub-proofs, each about as long as your original, direct proof (but symmetric to one another, so some might wave it away as "the other case is similar")

Comment: @BrianMoehring conclusion is $\alpha_1=\beta_1$ And $\alpha_2=\beta_2$, since $\alpha_1-\beta_1= \beta_2-\alpha_2=0_V$. Another way to say same thing is: since $\alpha_i\neq \beta_i$, $\alpha_i- \beta_i \neq 0_V$. But $\alpha_1- \beta_1=\beta_2-\alpha_2\in W_1\cap W_2=\{0_V\}$.  If $\beta_2=\alpha_2$(or $\beta_1=\alpha_1$), then we get straight contradiction.

Comment: Munkres certainly did not teach you to encode every mathematical sentence in symbols. In fact, he is very careful to avoid such a style. He writes words, not $\exists$, $\exists !$, $\forall$, etc.

Comment: @BrianMoehring do you agree with my conclusion or it have flaws?